# SQL Pivot on fixed columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, pivot-table

I'm trying to put together a report, but I'm not managing to generate the desired output.

```
WITH DATA_PIVOT AS
(
SELECT 'GNA' SIGL, 'RC752293' ID_USER, '20200609' DATE_FILE, '11:30' HR_INTERVAL1,  10 DURATION1, '13:00' HR_INTERVAL2, 60 DURATION2,   '15:00' HR_INTERVAL3, 10 DURATION3, 'ENTRADA' OPERATION, TO_DATE('09/06/2020 11:35:21', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') TIME_INTERVAL, 'DESCANCO' TYPE_OF_INTERVAL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GNA' , 'RC752293' ,     '20200609' , '11:30' ,  10 , '13:00' , 60 , '15:00' , 10 , 'SAIDA' , TO_DATE('09/06/2020 11:46:33', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'DESCANCO'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GNA' , 'RC752293' ,     '20200609' , '11:30' ,  10 , '13:00' , 60 , '15:00' , 10 , 'ENTRADA' , TO_DATE('09/06/2020 15:48:04', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'DESCANCO'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GNA' , 'RC752293' ,     '20200609' , '11:30' ,  10 , '13:00' , 60 , '15:00' , 10 , 'SAIDA' , TO_DATE('09/06/2020 16:01:44', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'DESCANCO'  FROM DUAL
)

SELECT * FROM DATA_PIVOT;
```

[image: Desired output:]
In the ideal world I managed to solve using MAX (DECODE ()) and would have the following sequence of records for an "ID_USER", but I have several records with the column "TYPE_OF_INTERVAL" missing (as an example of the image above). In the perfect world it would be:

```
WITH DATA_PIVOT AS
(
SELECT 'GNA' SIGL, 'RC752293' ID_USER, '20200609' DATE_FILE, '11:30' HR_INTERVAL1,  10 DURATION1, '13:00' HR_INTERVAL2, 60 DURATION2,   '15:00' HR_INTERVAL3, 10 DURATION3, 'ENTRADA' OPERATION, TO_DATE('09/06/2020 11:35:21', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') TIME_INTERVAL, 'DESCANCO' TYPE_OF_INTERVAL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GNA' , 'RC752293' ,     '20200609' , '11:30' ,  10 , '13:00' , 60 , '15:00' , 10 , 'SAIDA' , TO_DATE('09/06/2020 11:46:33', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'DESCANCO'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GNA' , 'RC752293' ,     '20200609' , '11:30' ,  10 , '13:00' , 60 , '15:00' , 10 , 'ENTRADA' , TO_DATE('09/06/2020 15:48:04', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'LANCHE'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GNA' , 'RC752293' ,     '20200609' , '11:30' ,  10 , '13:00' , 60 , '15:00' , 10 , 'SAIDA' , TO_DATE('09/06/2020 16:01:44', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'LANCHE'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GNA' , 'RC752293' ,     '20200609' , '11:30' ,  10 , '13:00' , 60 , '15:00' , 10 , 'ENTRADA' , TO_DATE('09/06/2020 17:48:04', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'DESCANCO'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GNA' , 'RC752293' ,     '20200609' , '11:30' ,  10 , '13:00' , 60 , '15:00' , 10 , 'SAIDA' , TO_DATE('09/06/2020 18:01:34', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'DESCANCO'  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM DATA_PIVOT;
```

[image: Perfect world]

In the ideal world I managed to solve using MAX (DECODE ()) and would have the following sequence of records for an "ID_USER", but I have several records with the column "TYPE_OF_INTERVAL" missing (as an example of the image above). In the perfect world it would be:

However, when records are missing from the TYPE_OF_INTERVAL column, I cannot format the types in their respective columns.
How can I generate the output using SQL with the Oracle 12C version? I'm totally lost and I don't know where else to go, I tried several PIVOT implementations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prepare data at first, for instance using `rank()`, so each `id` has numbered rows:

```
select data_pivot.*, 
       rank() over (partition by id_user, operation, type_of_interval 
                    order by time_interval) rn
  from data_pivot
```

Then you can make pivot:

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b20f2e86a0c53f11e93765f6ca90adb)</sup>**

```
select * 
  from (select data_pivot.*, 
               rank() over (partition by id_user, operation, type_of_interval 
                            order by time_interval) rn 
          from data_pivot) 
  pivot (max(time_interval) for (rn, operation, type_of_interval) in 
    ( (1, 'ENTRADA', 'DESCANCO') init1,
      (1, 'SAIDA',   'DESCANCO') end1,
      (1, 'ENTRADA', 'LANCHE')   init2,
      (1, 'SAIDA',   'LANCHE')   end2,
      (2, 'ENTRADA', 'DESCANCO') init3,
      (2, 'SAIDA',   'DESCANCO') end3
    ) )
```

Comment: Perfect in your answer! Thank you ! My implementation had been very similar, the difference was: `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_USER, OPERATION, TYPE_OF_INTERVAL  ORDER BY TIME_INTERVAL) RN`

Comment: You can test data so adjust `rank` accordingly. Be careful however, I don't know if in your data first `init` and `end` values may be null, in this case we may need more logic in data preparation.